# regex find block with code in markdown text

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I need to identify blocks with code in the markdown text.
The code can be identified using the following template:
```code```
******** - 8 characters, each of which can be a space or \r or \n

The first option is easy to find, but the second one is a bit tricky.
First of all, I can't figure out how to write down that any of the eight characters can be either \s or \r or \n - like [\s\n\r]{8}
Secondly, each line of the code block also contains 8 spaces or \r or \n - so when the code block ends, the normal text will start without spaces - I have no idea how to determine it

Example:

```
Some text\r\n\r\n    Code\r\n\r\n    code next line\r\n\r\n    another
line\r\n\r\nRegular text again
```

The result of the regex should be:

```
\r\n\r\n    Code\r\n\r\n    code next line\r\n\r\n    another line\r\n\r\n
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: First, `\s` swallows `\r` and `\n` so there is no need to write `[\s\r\n]` because it is exactly `\s`. Second, please clarify if you're seeking to any sequence of white spaces (like `\s{8}`), or 4 spaces after two newlines (like `\r\n\r\n[[:space:]]{4}`), or something other?

Comment: eight characters, any of which can take one of three values - space \r or \n. Now I have a sequence like the one in the example, but it can be just eight spaces or \n + seven spaces. "First, \s swallows \r and \n" - I checked it on several online regex services /\s/ and nowhere  \n or \t  don't match - only spaces.

Comment: [Definition](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp) of \s. I believe most useful site to work with regex: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). If you checked by manual matching to some text, I want to draw your attention to regex flags. Depending on them, `\n` could be not matched. `\t` on the other hand should always be matched with `\s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match you code line-by-line use `(?<=\s{8})([^\n]*)`.

To match it as single block you could try something like `(\s{8}[^\n]*)`

Comment: This is a good answer, but you need to understand that in this case I have a string where \n(\r) is two characters '\' and 'n', so '\s' cannot match them. Also, this code doesn't detect the end of the code block, which is the most difficult thing

Comment: @ValeraKvip Sorry, I'm confused. By `\n` you mean this exact two symbol, and not newline symbol?

Comment: Here's the catch. regex101 or any other services considers \r\n to be two characters, not a newline. Therefore, it was necessary to use the js environment for testing, then it works, you helped me understand it.  I have modified your code, please add it to your answer and I will mark the issue as solved. /\s{8}.*([^(\n|\r)]*)/gm